# Android WebView within ScrollView is not displaying all of the content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a WebView that is within a ScrollView. The problem I have is that I cannot see all of the contents of the WebView. The WebView takes up a certain amount of space (not enough to see all of the content), but when I try to scroll down to see more of the WebView, it only scrolls the outside ScrollView.

How can I resize the WebView so that it has a large enough height to show all of the content. This way when I scroll, even though I scroll down the ScrollView, I will be able to see all of the WebView content.

Right now, the ScrollView has MATCH_PARENT for height & width. The WebView also has MATCH_PARENT for height & width.

I hope this makes sense. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: As suggested, please show us the layout xml

Answer (score 0):

You not need to add `WebView` in `ScrollView`, Remove `ScrollView` & Just Add `WebView` inside `LinearLayout`.

Comment: The way I have it setup, I need the WebView to be inside the ScrollView.

Comment: can you post your XML Code ?

Comment: WebView has its own Scroll so it never would be ScrollView Child

Comment: FYI, a scrollview should only have one direct child to it. It could be the case where @Mathi has an wrong setup of the xml